# Mina deploy: `remote` command doesn't find my executable (after upgrade from 0.3 to 1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, mina

I have the following custom task:

```
desc "Performs a backup."
task backup: :environment do
  comment 'Performing backup'
  command %{backup perform --trigger=audit}
end
```

It gives the following error:

```
$ mina backup
-----> Performing backup
       bash: line 1: backup: command not found
       Connection to zugangfueralle01.nine.ch closed.

 !     Run Error
```

But when manually ssh'ing to the server and executing `$ backup perform --trigger=audit`, it works well.

Does `remote` miss some configuration which is loaded when ssh'ing manually?

Interestingly, this very same task worked perfectly in v0.3, but after upgrading to 1.0, it doesn't anymore

**Update**

I added `command %{source $HOME/.bash_profile; source $HOME/.bashrc;}` before the `backup` command to load the env. This works. Still I suspect mina should already load the env itself.